# ActiveMQ Redelivery - send invalid message to the back of the Q

Tags: java, activemq-classic, message-queue

Upon **Redelivery** how can I send the message to the back of the Q?
Currently, it sends the message to the front of the Q, consequently the other messages are stuck

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of context necessary to know exactly what you are doing and how it might be going wrong.  Add more details and even some code snippets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of exhaustion of redelivery, don't put the message back to the original queue, instead make use of the DLQ (deadletter queue) mechanism.

Example broker config:

```
<destinationPolicy>
  <policyMap>
    <policyEntries>
      <!-- Set the following policy on all queues using the '>' wildcard -->
      <policyEntry queue=">">
        <deadLetterStrategy>
            <!--
              Use the prefix 'DLQ.' for the destination name, and make
              the DLQ a queue rather than a topic
            -->
          <individualDeadLetterStrategy queuePrefix="DLQ." useQueueForQueueMessages="true"/>
        </deadLetterStrategy>
      </policyEntry>
    </policyEntries>
  </policyMap>
</destinationPolicy>
```

For more details see the [ActiveMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html).